# How Can I receive select-option values in the form action by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am an elementary programmer in javascript. 
So I have so many Questions. Today, i am wondering how the select-option values can transmit to the html form action value.
My script and  associated html code is same as below.

```
 <script
  ......
 var selectedLang3 = document.getElementById('lang3').value;
 var selectedPart = document.getElementById('part').values;
 xmlhttp.open("GET","hint_"+selectedLang3+"_"+selectedPart+".php?q="+str,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
  }
 </script>   
 <h5>Choose your language and the part that you want to know</h5>
  <select name="lang3" id="lang3">
    <option value="co">한국어</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="af">Afrikaans</option>
    ....
  </select>
```

And I have a form in this html code, for I can send my input data to php-MySQL query.
But above javascript code, I have to write above language select-option to use in above javascript code. So I want to re-use language select-option values in my form code. 
My form code is as like below.

```
<form action="query_<script var selecetedLang3; /script>.php" method="POST" 
 class="query" id="query">
 <h5> Subject </h5>:  <select name="subject2" id="subject2" size="1" style="width:45%;" >
     <option value="a">Infection : bacteria and virus </option>
     <option value="b">Infection : virus, fungus and etc</option>
      ...
      </select>
  <input type="text" name="search" onkeyup="showHint()">
  <input type="text" name="search1" onkeyup="showHint()">
   ---
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
  </form>
```

Here `showHint` javascript is omitted for the simple code. 
Above code, How can i write `action="???"`?
Please, Give me a piece of advice .
Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- first of all you can read the `value` from select elements like:

```
var lang3 = document.getElementById("lang3");
xmlhttp.open("GET","hint_"+ lang3.value + "_"+selectedPart+".php?q="+str,true);
```

2- and to be able to `POST` your form, with the select value in it as a part of your form which is going to be sent, you should create a `hiddenfield` with your preferred name, and bind the select node value to its value.

add it to html part:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lang" />
```

and do this in js part:

```
var lang3 = document.getElementById("lang3");
lang3.onchange = function(){
    document.querySelector("input[name=lang]").value = this.value;
}
```

do not forget this solution is used, **if you want to send the select value along with your form**.

3- your last point, is **how to change the action in form, so that you can send your form to a different php, based on selected language**, firstly, you don't need to use `type=submit` button, use a simple button and do this:

**Html part:**

```
<input type="button" onclick='submit_form()' />
```

**JS part**:

```
function submit_form() {
    var lang3 = document.getElementById('lang3');
    if(!lang3.value) alert("please select your language!");
    var queryForm = document.getElementById('query');
    queryForm.action = "query_" + lang3.value + ".php";
    queryForm.submit();
}
```

and this is your working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u94DL/1/).

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind answer. But I have to have time to understand your code 'cause I am lack of javascript knowledge. Sorry that you wait..

Comment: @Drohjho: if you want, we can have a 15 minutes chat, in this [chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46211/myjs) at 3:30PM UK time, I can clarify some basic points for you.

Comment: Thank you, I'm an elementary member in stackoverflow

Comment: Mr. Mehran Hatami, above code, Third js code is very difficult, so I cannot use that code where.

Comment: What i want to know is '<form action="query_<script> var Lang3; </script>.php" ..'. That is, as like query_co, query_en, query_ja...

Comment: @Drohjho: check it 2 hours from now, I am in middle of something right now, as soon as I get home, I,ll create a working sample for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr.Mehran Hatami. I'll wait for your kind reply.

Comment: @Drohjho: now you can check my answer.

Comment: @Drohjho: you're welcome. I usually post some JavaScript lessons in this [link](http://aroku.org/category/javascript-lessons/), you can check them occasionally and ask your questions. Cheers:)